# Obtaining Read/Write Lock for Sqlite Parallel Updates

Tags: sqlite, parallel-processing

I write a lot of parallel scripts in python for research purposes and was wondering if it is possible to obtain a read/write lock manually in sqlite for a specific set of commands.  Here is an oversimplified example of why I need it:

**Simple Example:**
*Suppose I have a table (**A**) and I want to simply count the number of rows in it and store the result in another table (**B**) in parallel.  To do so, I run 10 instances of a program that counts rows for a certain range of **A** and adds the sum of the rows to the property in **B**.*

*The problem is that I need to read the property in B, add it to the instance's count, and save it; all while making sure none of the other instances are doing this process.  Normally it is only a write lock that is needed - in this case I need a read lock as well...*

**I was hoping I could do something like this:**

1. read/write lock
2. Grab current value in **B**, add it to the
   instance count
3. save new value
4. unlock

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increment an integer value using a single `UPDATE` statement:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE B(Id INTEGER, Value INTEGER);
sqlite> INSERT INTO B VALUES(0, 15);
sqlite> UPDATE B SET Value=Value + 23 WHERE Id = 0;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM B;
0|38
sqlite>
```

Using a single `UPDATE` statement makes this operation atomic, making any extra locking unnecessary.

If you need more complex processing, you can use [SQL transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) to ensure that any complex database operations are performed atomically.

In general, you should avoid any locking external to SQLite or messing with the SQLite locking subsystem - doing so is a very good recipe for deadlocks...

EDIT:

To append to a string, you can use the `||` concatenation operator:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE C(Id INTEGER, Value TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO C VALUES(0, 'X');
sqlite> UPDATE C SET Value=Value || 'Y' WHERE Id = 0;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM C;
0|XY
sqlite>
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for.  I'm assuming I could do the same thing if Value were a string?

Comment: @sequenceGeek: not exactly the same, but similar :-)